# How to deploy multiple applications in Tomcat, share jars and have different datasources?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I want to deploy three Grails web applications in a Tomcat container. I am using Grails 1.3.7 and Tomcat 7.0.23. I want to put all commons jars in a tomcat/shared/lib directory. Why? I want to have smaller war files and reduce the amount of memory required in PermGen.

I configure the next line in *conf/catalina.properites*

```
shared.loader=${catalina.base}/shared/lib,${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar
```

For all three applications, I execute

```
  grails war
```

I copy all the *.jars under WEB-INF/lib into $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib

Later I generate the war files without jars for every application

```
grails war --nojars
```

I put all three wars in the *tomcat/webapps* directory. The production dataSource in *conf/DataSource.groovy* looks as follows for every app.

App A)

```
   production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            username = "userA"
            password="password"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/applicationA"
            driverClassName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
        }
    }
```

App B)

```
   production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            username = "userB"
            password="password"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/applicationB"
            driverClassName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
        }
    }
```

App C)

```
   production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            username = "userC"
            password="password"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/applicationC"
            driverClassName = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
        }
    }
```

When I start up Tomcat the logs look like this:

```
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 652 ms
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationB-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationA-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationC-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/docs
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/examples
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@5f24aa56')
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/host-manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationB-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationA-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationC-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/docs
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/examples
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@55e610e3')
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/host-manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationB-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationA-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationC-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/docs
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/examples
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@75ea2543')
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/host-manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationB-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationA-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationC-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/docs
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/examples
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/host-manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/manager
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ROOT
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 19073 ms
```

The applications start up and I can reach them. **However, The only Application which has a working datasource connection is the last context loaded.**

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /Applications/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/webapps/ApplicationC-0.1war
Dec 11, 2011 11:28:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

What can I do to solve this?

### SOLUTION FOR 1.3.7

Some of the jars generated in a grais war command cannot be shared between every application.

**Jars which cannot be shared** and should be in  webapps/appA/WEB-INF/lib

```
grails-bootstrap-1.3.7.jar      
grails-gorm-1.3.7.jar           
grails-web-1.3.7.jar
grails-core-1.3.7.jar           
grails-resources-1.3.7.jar      
spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
grails-crud-1.3.7.jar           
grails-spring-1.3.7.jar
```

**Jars which can be shared** and can be in tomcat/shared/lib

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar                     
aopalliance-1.0.jar                 
asm-3.3.1.jar                       
asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar                  
asm-tree-3.3.1.jar                  
asm-util-3.3.1.jar                  
aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar                 
aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar                 
c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar                    
cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar                   
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar             
commons-codec-1.4.jar                   
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar               
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar                    
commons-el-1.0.jar                  
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar                
commons-io-1.4.jar                  
commons-lang-2.4.jar                    
commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar                 
commons-pool-1.5.5.jar                  
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar             
concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.0_jdk5.jar        
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                     
ehcache-core-1.7.1.jar                  
ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar                       
groovy-all-1.7.8.jar                    
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar          
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar      
hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar             
hibernate-ehcache-3.3.1.GA.jar              
hibernate-validator-3.1.0.GA.jar            
hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar                 
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar                 
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar                
jsoup-1.6.1.jar     
jstl-1.1.2.jar  
jta-1.1.jar 
jul-to-slf4j-1.5.8.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar      
org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
parboiled-core-1.0.2.jar
parboiled-java-1.0.2.jar
pegdown-1.1.0.jar
remark-0.9.3.jar
sitemesh-2.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar
```

### SOLUTION FOR 2.0.0

Some of the jars generated in a grais war command cannot be shared between every application.

**Jars which cannot be shared** and should be in  webapps/appA/WEB-INF/lib

```
grails-bootstrap-2.0.0.jar
grails-core-2.0.0.jar
grails-crud-2.0.0.jar
grails-datastore-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-gorm-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
grails-datastore-simple-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
grails-hibernate-2.0.0.jar
grails-logging-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-codecs-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-controllers-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-converters-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-datasource-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-domain-class-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-filters-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-gsp-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-i18n-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-log4j-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-mimetypes-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-scaffolding-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-services-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-servlets-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-url-mappings-2.0.0.jar
grails-plugin-validation-2.0.0.jar
grails-resources-2.0.0.jar
grails-spring-2.0.0.jar
grails-web-2.0.0.jar
```

**Jars which can be shared** and can be in tomcat/shared/lib

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar
asm-tree-3.3.1.jar
asm-util-3.3.1.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.10.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.10.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.6.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.2_jdk5.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ecj-3.6.2.jar
ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar
fontbox-1.6.0.jar
h2-1.2.147.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.7.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-3.6.7.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar
jsoup-1.6.1.jar
jstl-1.1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.6.2.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
parboiled-core-1.0.2.jar
parboiled-java-1.0.2.jar
pdfbox-1.6.0.jar
pegdown-1.1.0.jar
poi-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar
remark-0.9.3.jar
sitemesh-2.4.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't work in Grails, and there are a few more issues than the datasource. We looked at fixing this for 2.0 but there are still issues, so it won't work until a 2.0.x release.

The problem is static variables in the core Grails jars. Since the classes in those jars are loaded by the shared classloader, the statics are shared throughout Tomcat. As long as the jars are in each war file they're loaded by the war-specific classloader and there's no conflict between static variables. So until this is fixed you need to deploy full wars, or at least keep the grails-*.jar files in the wars.

Comment: I kept the grails-*.jar in the WEB-INF/lib and it seems to work fine. Appreciate the efforts to fix this, great news if it comes soon to grails 2.0.

Comment: I have four apps. One of them uses the spring security core plugin. It is not working properly. Do you know if there is a dependency there too? Are there other jars apart from grails-*.jar which should not be shared? You really helped me. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't aware of shared-jar problems with spring-security-core - please write up an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE and I'll take a a look.

Comment: I think I claim to soon a problem with spring security core jars. I am running fine with them shared. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

It's a nice idea and I usually try to do the same (share jars across contexts). However, not all jars can be shared this way (they have to be designed for it).

1. The shared libs are loaded in another (shared) Classloader, higher in the Classloading hierarchy. If you try to find classes by name, you will not be able to find Classes in a Classloader lower in the hierarchy.
2. Some classes/jars use the Singleton Pattern (or another kind of state). If you put them in a war, they will be loaded multiple times and multiple Singletons exists (one for each war). If you put them in a shared context, it won't work like this.

My advise would be to only put jars in the shared context that have been explicitly designed for it. Test it and you'll see. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, the problem is knowing which jar files can be shared. I have put a list in the question trying to draw a line between files that can be shared and files that cannot be shared.